# Issues with using CKEDITOR built-in templates

Tags: css, ckeditor

I am trying to use the default templates available with CKEDITOR.So I choose the one where an image and text can be placed side by side i.e. the image is occupying a certain part of the editor and the text the remaining part(but on the same horizontal level.I hope you get my point).But when I paste an image into the image area(provided in the template) , the text automatically shifts itself towards the bottom of the image(i.e. now image and text are not on the same level anymore). This happens no matter whether the size of the area provided for the image is bigger or smaller than the image.
           Can any one say why this is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Image Alignment To get the text in the same horizontal level

Image Properties ->  Image Info -> Alignment -> Left | Right